# Table layout / swift - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, swift

i'm trying to re-create this view in iOS using swift.

I saw this example on this site:
http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-data-grid-table-view/586

Unfortunately I do not know very well the language objective-C.

Can anyone help me by giving me some advice on the implementation?

Comment: That you can do easily with a CollectionView. Anyway your question is too broad. Please ask only specific questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom cell or prototype cell and use the basic tableview delegate methods. that will work for you.

Your basic method would be as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var simpleTableIdentifier:NSString="ViewController1"
        var cell:ViewController1?=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as? ViewController1
        if (cell == nil) {
            var nib:NSArray=NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewController1", owner: self, options: nil)

          cell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as? ViewController1
        }

        cell!.label1.text = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? NSString



        return cell
    }
```

use the same UI and Labels which suits to single row and repeat it according to your record.